# Retrieve two colums of data with one join

Tags: sql

I'm trying to display a list of paired people.

I have a link table looking like the following:

| id | user_id_one | user_id_two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

I wanna retrieve the names linked to these id's from the main user table looking like:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | jef |
| 2 | kevin |
| 3 | mike |
| 4 | sam |

I just can't seem to figure it out. I tried the following:

```
SELECT name 
FROM users a 
INNER JOIN link_table b ON a.id = b.user_id_one 
INNER JOIN link_table b ON a.id = b.user_id_two
```

This won't fetch anything. When commenting out one of the two joins I do get values. So my question is: How do I fetch two columns of data from the same table that they are linked to?

The big thing is, I just don't know what to google since I am fairly new to SQL. I'm thinking I need a sub query in the select part to make it two separate columns, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Show us sample data for both tables, and also make sure the specified result matches the sample data.

Comment: You need different table aliases for each link_table instance.

Comment: As jarlh suggests, try to change for example the alias in your second join:
INNER JOIN link_table c /*instead of b */ ON a.id = b.user_id_two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the users table twice to the link table, not the opposite:

```
select l.id,
user_id_one,
u1.name as user_id_one_name,
user_id_two,
u2.name as user_id_two_name
from link_table l
inner join users u1 on l.user_id_one = u1.id
inner join users u2 on l.user_id_two = u2.id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ed6dd8a67113829cd5977668e5a6e95)